# Celery version compatibility issue

Tags: python, django, celery

I am not able to configure the already existing django project.The project is handled with `fabric` and using commands I have installed all the packages and I am getting "`ImportError: cannot import name Celery`" error in my code as shown here in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/splnI.png).

The directory structure is as below:

```
- proj/
  - manage.py
  - fabfile.py
  - proj/
    - __init__.py
    - celery.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
```

**The celery.py**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '.env'))
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings.development')
app = Celery('electric_soul')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

The ***ini*.py** file is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__version__ = '1.0.1-dev'
__version_info__ = tuple([int(num) if num.isdigit() else num for num in __version__.replace('-', '.', 1).split('.')])
from .celery import app as celery_app  # noqa
```

**Tried**:

1. I have changed the name of celery.py
2. I have added the `from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals` at first line on ***ini*.py** and **celery.py**.

Comment: Are you sure the exception was raised from the same place when you tried 1.? In my experience, it fixed the problem in the past...

Comment: I reproduced your problem in this sample project and simply adding 2. (without 1.) fixed it: https://github.com/browniebroke/celery-experiement

Comment: I have tried both case, Still getting same issue

Comment: It is probably confused what celery you want to import from. You have a local "celery" module that shadows the Celery package... Why you decided to have that `celery.py` is beyond me...